# Linux: Where to define my aliases regardless of the shell being used?

Tags: linux, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Void Linux in WSL with the `fish` shell. I want to define aliases, but I am not sure why they are not being executed. When I used `zsh` everything seemed to work.

I want the aliases to be defined regardless of the shell being used.

I have tried putting them in `etc/rc.local`, `etc/profile` and inside `/etc/profile.d/`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `/etc/profile.d/` is fine and the best place to put common aliases. You're doing nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3665#issuecomment-268327507), fish is not POSIX-compatible, and it doesn't read `/etc/profile`.

I suggest you use one of the configuration files listed in [fish documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My questions still remains; Is there a place that is relevant for all shells? I understand that fish is not POSIX-compatible but I would still like to have the same configuration for any shell I use and not fish specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that this solution is probably *gross overkill <sup>1</sup>* for the question at hand, but `nix`+`home-manager` *<sup>2</sup>* allows you to create shell-agnostic aliases in the `~/.config/home-manager/home.nix` file.  For example, I have defined (simplified):

```
{
    home.shellAliases = {
        ls = "exa --header --icons --classify";
        ll = "exa -l --header --icons --classify";
        la = "exa -a --header --icons --classify";
    };

    # Have home-manager create and manage the config files for these shells:
    programs.bash.enable = true;
    programs.fish.enable = true;
}
```

Zsh (and more) is also supported.

As mentioned in the [help](https://rycee.gitlab.io/home-manager/options.html#opt-home.shellAliases):

> This option should only be used to manage simple aliases that are compatible across all shells. If you need to use a shell specific feature then make sure to use a shell specific option, for example `programs.bash.shellAliases` for Bash.

---

*<sup>1</sup>* Overkill, because Nix essentially overlays an entirely separate distribution on top of your existing distribution (Void, in this case).  That said, there are a lot of benefits to Nix, so I'm using it with WSL so that each of the distributions I run in WSL has all of my client apps pre-configured the way I like them.

Before Nix, I was using Ansible for essentially the same purpose (also overkill), but that requires different *Ansible* configuration for each distribution.  Nix, by overlaying *its* set of applications on top of the distribution, abstracts that away.

(Side-note for other readers:  Don't worry, I typically test out most of my answers here on Super User and other SE sites in a fresh distribution without Nix, so that I'm attempting to reproduce problems in a similar environment to the one most users will be running.)

---

*<sup>2</sup>* Note that there is a big difference between NixOS and Nix, and it's hard to figure that out when first learning about Nix.  NixOS is a distribution itself based entirely on Nix.  Nix (as a language and packaging system) can run on most any distribution, although I have not tried it with Void specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I need to think about it. I was hoping there is a standard way to do it in Linux.

Comment: @RandallFlagg What types of aliases are you trying to add?  Replacements for standard commands (e.g. `ls` alias)?  Or helper aliases for things you do often, but which have their own unique names?  For the later, the more "Linux Standard" alternative would be a shell script with a shebang line - That could execute in *any* of your shells the same way.  The limitations would be that shell scripts can't modify the environment (variables, PWD, etc.).  I can provide a more complete answer based on that if it seems like a possible solution for you.